# How to add a ring around bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do you add a ring around bootstrap glyphs, without using a solid circle? I have seen an example where you just sit a glyph over the top of the circle glyph, but then you don't get the correct background colour, as shown below.

[image: Example]

Comment: How about using `border` and `border-radius` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an example of how to display and position an icon inside another (circle) div with modular background/color/border options.

See working Snippet.

```css
/**CSS FOR THE RING**/

.glyphicon-ring {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  color: white;
  display: inline-table;
  text-align: center;
}
/**CSS FOR ICON WITH NO BACKGROUND COLOR**/

.glyphicon-ring .glyphicon-bordered {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
/**WITH AN ADDED BACKGROUND COLOR**/

.glyphicon-white {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
.glyphicon-teal {
  background: teal;
  color: orange;
}
.glyphicon-red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil glyphicon-bordered"></span>

        </div>
      </div>
      <h4>Transparent Defaults</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-white"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil glyphicon-bordered"></span>

        </div>
      </div>
      <h4>Background Color + Icon Color + Border Color</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-red"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil glyphicon-bordered"></span>

        </div>
      </div>
      <h4>Background Color + Default Icon Color</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil glyphicon-bordered"></span>

        </div>
      </div>
      <h4>Background Color + Icon Color</h4>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: if using this snippet inside a table, add `border-collapse: initial;` to `.glyphicon-ring`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `border-radius`, you'll probably need to tweak the `height` and `width` values.

```
.glyph{
   height:2em;
   width:2em;
   border-radius:50%;
   border:3px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: just gave a try  to it - http://kagda.ru/i/d9011230d9298_26-02-2017-22:50:53_d901.png .Any ideas how to make it in center?

Comment: `text-align:center;`

Comment: maybe adding a bit of padding will help with vertical and horizontal centering