# bootstrap place text centered beside circled icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the following CSS and HTML code to "draw" a circle around each font-awesome & glyphicon icon (css adapeted from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846244/how-to-add-a-ring-around-bootstrap-glyphicons)):

```
.glyphicon-ring {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  color: white;
  display: inline-table;
  text-align: center;
}

.glyphicon-ring .glyphicon-bordered {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.glyphicon-teal {
  background: teal;
  color: orange;
}

<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="alert alert-info">
   <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
        <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to place some text to the right side (besides) the image, so it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Anything you've already tried on your own?

Comment: Of course, using `<p class"text-right">test</p>` doesn't work at all

Comment: i think this question has answer here

Comment: Well, simply adding a <span> tag is kinda enough for me. Some css would be left to achieve your exact example, but still it already is besides of the image: https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/BpymRr

Comment: @Aer0 yes this works, but the text is not placed that fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
  font-size:10px;
}

.glyphicon-ring {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  color: white;
  display: inline-table;
  text-align: center;
}

.glyphicon-ring .glyphicon-bordered {
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.glyphicon-teal {
  background: teal;
  color: orange;
}


.margin_top{
 margin-top: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
 .margin_top{
  margin-top: 10px !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
 
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
 <div class="row alert alert-info" style="margin:0;padding:5px;">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
          <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center" style="padding:0;">
     <p style="padding-top: 10px;"> Here Some Text </p>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class=" col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
 <div class="row alert alert-info" style="margin:0;padding:5px;">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
          <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center" style="padding:0;">
     <p style="padding-top: 10px;"> Here Some Text </p>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class=" col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 ">
 <div class="row alert alert-info" style="margin:0;padding:5px;">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
          <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center" style="padding:0;">
     <p style="padding-top: 10px;"> Here Some Text </p>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class=" col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 margin_top">
 <div class="row alert alert-info" style="margin:0;padding:5px;">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
          <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
      </div>
     </div>
 </div> 

 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center" style="padding:0;">
     <p style="padding-top: 10px;"> Here Some Text </p>
 </div>
</div>

</div>



</div>
</div>
```

Is this the same that you want?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7asoytw/1/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

write something like this: i think below code will help you.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="alert alert-info">
   <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
        <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="alert alert-info">
  ..................... Here Some text.............
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

OR you can write like this

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="display:inline-block">
<div class="alert alert-info">
   <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
        <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="display:inline-block">
<div class="alert alert-info">
      ..................... Here Some text.............
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="alert alert-info">
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
        <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="alert alert-info">
  ..................... Here Some text.............
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: @wichtel add this some css, like manage font of text and size of glyphicon

Answer (score 0):

This works well.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="alert alert-info">
  <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
    <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
  </div>
 <p style="display:inline;margin-left:10px;">Here some text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like This.

```css
.glyphicon-ring {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  color: white;
  display: inline-table;
  text-align: center;
}

.glyphicon-ring .glyphicon-bordered {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.glyphicon-teal {
  background: teal;
  color: orange;
}
.alert{
 position: relative;
}
.right-text {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 38%;
}
```

```html
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="alert alert-info">
   <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
        <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
        <div class="right-text">Here some text</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="alert alert-info">
   <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
        <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
        <div class="right-text">Here some text</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="alert alert-info">
   <div class="glyphicon-ring glyphicon-teal">
        <span class="fa fa-lock glyphicon-bordered"></span>
        <div class="right-text">Here some text</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```